# Execution order in Java

Tags: java, loops

Here is a part of my code:

```
 Thread refreshHistory=new Thread(()->{
        try{
            while(true){
                todoDA.refreshHistory();
                Thread.sleep(secondsToWait*1000);

            }
        }catch(Exception e){}
    });
```

Is there a way to make sure that `todoDA.refreshHistory();` will be always executed **before** thread goes to sleep?

I was having `Abort due to constraint violation (NOT NULL constraint failed: Tag_todo.todo_id)`. At this code:

First Class:

```
Todo createdTodo=null;
if(typePicker.getValue().getName().equals("1")){
            TodoCalendar todoCalendar=todoDA.createTodoCalendar(lDate,todoTime.toString());
            if(newGroup.isSelected()){
                todoDA.createTodo(todoNameString, description, importancePicker.getValue(), newGroupObject, timerType, typePicker.getValue(), null, todoCalendar);
            }else{
                    createdTodo=todoDA.createTodo(todoNameString, description, importancePicker.getValue(), groupPicker.getValue(), timerType, typePicker.getValue(), null, todoCalendar);
                }
        }else if(typePicker.getValue().getName().equals("2")){
            TodoWeek todoWeek=todoDA.createTodoWeek(mondayTime, tuesdayTime, wednesdayTime, thursdayTime, fridayTime, saturdayTime, sundayTime);
            if(newGroup.isSelected()){
                todoDA.createTodo(todoNameString, description, importancePicker.getValue(), newGroupObject, timerType, typePicker.getValue(),todoWeek,null);
            }else{
                    createdTodo=todoDA.createTodo(todoNameString, description, importancePicker.getValue(), groupPicker.getValue(), timerType, typePicker.getValue(),todoWeek, null);
                }
        }else if(typePicker.getValue().getName().equals("3")){
            TodoCalendar todoCalendar=todoDA.createTodoCalendar(lDate,null);
            if(newGroup.isSelected()){
                todoDA.createTodo(todoNameString, description, importancePicker.getValue(), newGroupObject, timerType, typePicker.getValue(), null, todoCalendar);
            }else{
                    createdTodo=todoDA.createTodo(todoNameString, description, importancePicker.getValue(), groupPicker.getValue(), timerType, typePicker.getValue(), null, todoCalendar);
                }
        }
        /*********************************************************WORK WITH TAGS***************************************************************************/
        if(!allTags.equals("")){
        for(int i=0;i<tagsList.length;i++){
            String readyTag=tagsList[i].trim();
            if(!readyTag.equals("")){
                readyTag=readyTag.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");//get rid of not needed spaces
                todoDA.createConnectTag(readyTag,createdTodo);
            }//not empty tag
        }//go through all tags
        }//end if tags not empty
```

Second class:

```
public void createConnectTag(String myTag, Todo todo){
Session session=mainApp.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Tag createdTag=new Tag(tag);
session.save(createdTag);
TagTodo tagTodo=new TagTodo(createdTag, todo);
session.save(tagTodo);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();}
```

It seems that my object is passed as null(sometimes it works fine). Even though at that time it should be already created. If I add several `System.out.println();` before calling `createConnectTag(readyTag,createdTodo);` everything also works. So I was wondering how to call `createConnectTag(readyTag,createdTodo);` after `createTodo` finished executing?

Most times this code works fine, but sometimes I'm getting a mistake.

Comment: It already will.  Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: the code inside your loop is inside a thread but is not calling a threaded function, todoDA.refreshHistory  will be executed before going to sleep.

Comment: It's just sometimes when I'm having `setFunction();` and after that `executeFunction();` I run into `NullPointerException`. So I tried to figure out how to solve possible issue. But I only found how to executedifferent threads in order.

Comment: the method todoDA.refreshHistory() will run under the application basic Thread and it has not to dot with the custom Thread you created.Except if you have parameters that are based from refreshHistory Thread..

Comment: You'll need to edit the question to include a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the behavior you're seeing. Statements within a single thread will *always* behave as if in the order they are written so if you see something which differs from that, there is something else going on.

Comment: Also `catch(Exception e){}`? What if `todoDA.refreshHistory();` throws a NullPointerException or something like that? It will appear not to execute but it's because you've eaten the exception. See my previous comment. At the very least do something like `catch(InterruptedException e){throw new AssertionError(e);}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call will always happen before your Thread goes to sleep. As you are obviously having a problem in a greater context than just one Thread, it depends on your function what will be executed next.

Comment: I added part of my code, where I was having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

your code will execute by order, so the the line `todoDA.refreshHistory();`will execute first,then the thread will sleep,
but when the line `todoDA.refreshHistory();` start another thread, then the second thread will start at a uncertain time